# Pivot works in Small Range but not in large

Tags: vba, excel

I have written below code to generate a pivot from sheet named Data it works if data is till column Z if the data goes beyond col Z. it does not work.

Need Someone to check the code & help me figure out what could be the possible error here.

Sub pivot()

```
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Data")
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="Status")
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Status")

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Status").PivotFields("Region")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Status").PivotFields("Final Owner")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Status").PivotFields("Incident ID")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlCount
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    .Name = "Count"
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your `PivotCache` line to:

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)). _
            CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), TableName:="Status")
```

Comment: @ish anything ? some credit for helping you, jeese :)